# Resampling without changing pitch and ratio

Tags: python, speech-recognition, torch, resampling, torchaudio

I'm doing speech recognition and denoising. In order to feed the data to my model I need to resample and make it 2 channels. although I don't know the optimized resampling rate for each sound. when I use a fixed number for resampling rate(resr) like 20000 or 16000 sometimes it works and sometimes it makes the pitch wrong or makes it slow. How does resampling work in this case? Do I need an optimizer?
Also what can I do if I have a phone call and one person's voice is too quiet that it indeed gets recognized as noise?

This is my code:

```
num_channels = sig.shape[0]
# Resample first channel
resig = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(sr, resr)(sig[:1,:])
print(resig.shape)
if (num_channels > 1):
# Resample the second channel and merge both channels
   retwo = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(sr,resr)(sig[1:,:])
   resig = torch.cat([resig, retwo])
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know the optimized resampling rate for each sound

Sample rate is not a parameter you tune for each audio, rather, the same sample rate that was used to train the speech recognition model should be used.

> sometimes it works and sometimes it makes the pitch wrong or makes it slow.

Resampling when properly done, does not alter pitch or speed. I guess that you are saving the resulting data with wrong sample rate. Sample rate is not something you can pick an arbitrary number. You have to pick a one that conforms to the system you are working with.

---

Having said that the proper way to do resampling, regardless of the number of channels is to simply pass the waveform to `torchaudio.functional.resample` function with original and target sample rate. The function process multiple channels at the same time, so there is no need to run resample function separately for each channel.

Then, if you know the sample rate of input audio beforehand, and all the audio you process have the same sample rate, using `torchaudio.transforms.Resample` will make the process faster because it will cache the convolution kernel used for resampling.

```py
resampler = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(original_sample_rate, target_sample_rate)

for sig in signals:
    resig = resampler(sig)
    # process the resulting resampled signal
```